# dotTrace ошибка при открытии процесса

Tags: c#, resharper

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При использовании пунктов Profile Local App на службу (например, веб публикаций или мою собственную) вылетает подобная ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина крылась в свойстве службы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Служба **не** должна иметь доступа к рабочему столу!

Иначе dotTrace с ней работать не умеет...